# Acer Aspire V5-571G Recovery Partition

Tags: acer-aspire, factory-defaults

I bought an Acer Aspire V5-571pg early last year. I remembered at the time that the C drive was too big. I normally have a large collection of data which I store in the E (data) drive away from the OS drive. So naturally I used partition magic to resize. Little did I know that it is causing me such grief when I try to do a restore.

At this point, I need to restore the system to the factory default. In doing so, I get this error:

"Hard drive configuration is not set to the factory default. Restore aborted."

Upon checking the partition, the drive structure appears to be:

1. Unallocated: 1MB
2. OEM Partition: 400MB
3. EFI System Partition: 300MB
4. Other: 128MB
5. ACER C: 194.55GB
6. Recovery Partition: 350MB
7. DATA E: 488.28GM
8. Push Button Reset: 14.65GB
9. Unallocated: 871KB

Why the hell does ACER need so many bloody partitions? And why did they put the recovery drive smack bang in between drive C and E. In any case, I believe that it could be the fact that I resized the drive and shifted the Recovery Partition to the left causing the restore to fail to read the start of the recovery section.

I can't even begin to fathom where it originally was, as there is no manual to cover such issue. Does anyone know how Acer Recovery Utility determine what section of the drive to look for? And if so, what section is it so that I can use the Partition magic to put it back in the right place?

Answer (score -1):

What comes to mind:

- Go back in time and burn recovery DVDs.
- Try asking Acer support / [forums](http://community.acer.com/t5/Discussion-Forums/ct-p/boards), that's probably your best chance of finding someone who really knows about Acer recovery partitions.
- Forget about it and reinstall windows yourself.
  Download windows iso from microsoft (possible for [windows 7](http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/boot-disks.html#full), probably for windows 8 as well) and reinstall using the key on your laptop sticker. Install missing drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Badly managed partitioning structure, causes system to work slower too; unalocated space assigned by OS will be higher than on your drive, but all the other drives highly advisable to wipe out.
 The recovery drive can be active partition- nowadays there are plenty better solutions, no reasons keeping this mess if you can manage it yourself.